# Getting error when trying to pass integer to method - iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, function, methods, int

I have a UIButton which when pressed passes an integer to a simple method I have set up. However I keep on getting this error:

```
Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'id' is disallowed with ARC
```

Here is my code:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(show:) withObject:prev_image afterDelay:2.0];
```

The reason I'm not just doing `[self show:prev_image]` is because I want a delay before the method is called.

Thanks for your time, Dan.

Comment: now read the documentation of `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`.

Comment: Is prev_image an int?

Comment: Yes pref_image is an integer. And I just read the performSelector:withObject:afterDelay documentation... so How the hell do I pass an int??

Comment: This question did not deserve as many down-votes as it received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prev_image is an int where an 'object' must be passed into the performSelector method.

I would advise that you do this:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(show:) withObject:@(prev_image) afterDelay:2.0f];
```

I would also recommend you change `prev_image` to `prevImage` whilst programming in Objective-C simply for style.

Using `dispatch_after` is not necessary here and you almost certainly want to stay as high level as possible when tackling problems in iOS development.

I apologise for being unclear.

You will also want to change the method signature and implementation of `show:`

```
- (void)show:(NSNumber *)number
{
    NSInteger integerNumber = [number integerValue];
}
```

Comment: This also requires that the `show:` method be changed to take an `NSNumber` instead of an `int`. And there is nothing "low level" about GCD. It's actually far more versatile and useful than using `performWithSelector...`.

Comment: Superb solution man! I wouldn't have thought of that. Although I really don't see any problem with using dispatch_after.

Comment: There is no problem with using dispatch_after, but I recommend staying as high-level as the solution allows.

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices:

1. Change the `show:` method to take an `NSNumber` and then wrap `prev_image` in an `NSNumber` or
2. Use `dispatch_after`.

Code:

```
double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [self show:prev_image];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use `[NSNumber numberWithInt:prev_image]` instead of prev_image. Also you'll need to change the show: method to to take an NSNumber instead of an int.

Comment: This also requires that the `show:` method be changed to take an `NSNumber` instead of an `int`.